# what do iterators actually point to in a container?

Tags: c++, stl

```
set <vector<int> > myset;
vector<int> v1= { 34,634,758,46,64 };
vector<int >v2= {325, 7457, 586, 865};
myset.insert(v1);
myset.insert(v2);
set<vector<int> > ::iterator it;
it = myset.begin();
for (; it != myset.end(); it++)
{
    vector<int> ::const_iterator temp = (*it);

}
```

I know that (it) is pointing to a vector so if i write vector ::const_iterator temp=(*it) , temp should point to first element of the vector? 
why is this not happening ? what does a iterator actually point to in a container ? how will i traverse the container in such a situation ?

Comment: `(*it)` ===> `(*it).cbegin()`

Comment: `*it` should give you the  first `vector` in the `set` (`vector<int> temp` or `const vector<int> & temp` depending on how much copying you want to do). If you want a `const` iterator to that `vector`, use `it->cbegin();`

Comment: @WhozCraig why not `it->cbegin()`?

Comment: @user4581301 you don't need `cbegin()`, because the vector is `const`, being the key of a `set`

Comment: Good to know. Thanks.

Comment: @n.m. No particular reason whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that (it) is pointing to a vector

No.  It refers to an element of the `set`, not to the content (a `vector`) held within that element.

> so if i write `vector ::const_iterator temp=(*it)` , `temp` should point to first element of the vector?

No.  When you dereference `it`, you are accessing the `vector` itself that is held within the `set` element.  You are not accessing any of the `vector`'s elements.  For that, you need to use the `vector`'s own methods, eg:

```
set< vector<int> > myset;
...
set< vector<int> >::iterator it;
for(it = myset.begin(); it != myset.end(); ++it)
{
    vector<int>::const_iterator temp = (*it).begin(); // or: it->begin()
    /* which is the same as doing this:
    vector<int> &v = *it;
    vector<int>::const_iterator temp = v.begin();
    */
}
```

> why is this not happening ?

Because there is no implicit conversion from a `vector&` to a `vector::const_iterator`.

> what does a `iterator` actually point to in a container ?

That is implementation-defined.  But in general, an iterator is a conceptual index/pointer to an element of the container.  You have to dereference the iterator to access the content of that element.

> how will i traverse the container in such a situation ?